# Can't get anchor tags to work in jquery mobile after form submit

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a simple internal website that I'm setting up to manage customer accounts at my work. I'm writing it in jquery mobile and have had moderate luck so far after a few initial issues. I'm stuck at one that I have no idea how to get past so any help would be appreciated.

I have the page with id=barcode that works fine when I type in index.php#barcode (although all the variables are empty as I haven't run the form yet), but once I submit the form, index.php#barcode only takes me to the first page in my index.php file and not the barcode page any more even when I type index.php#barcode manually. Only once I browse to index.php directly then add the #barcode again can I get to the barcode page, but when I do that it loses all the variables.

I have copied the content of the barcode page to the first page on index.php so I can see that the form works correctly and displays the information I'm looking for, but I can't work out why it only loads that page after I have submitted the form. I'm able to load other pages by typing in their anchor tags or clicking the buttons, but this specific page won't load and I have no idea why. Any ideas? I don't even know which parts of my code to post because I have no idea where the problem is occurring.

EDIT
Here's the code. It's split up over lots of different files that are included in each other, so hopefully this isn't too hard to understand;

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>XLX Internal Dashboard</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        include 'core/init.php';
        if(loggedin()==FALSE) {
            include 'login.php';
        } else {
            include 'landingpage.php';
            include 'customerlookup.php';
            include 'barcode.php';
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

landingpage.php

```
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>XLX Dashboard</h1>
    </div>

            <?php include 'includes/menu.php';
                $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
                $barcodesearch = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE barcode='$barcode'");
                while($row = $barcodesearch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $balance = $row['balance'];
                }
            ?>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>This is the landing page.</p>
        <p>Barcode = <?php echo $barcode;?></p>
        <p>Name = <?php echo $name;?></p>
        <p>Balance = $<?php echo $balance;?></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>XLX Glen Iris</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

barcode.php (displays before form is submitted but not afterwards)

```
<div data-role="page" id="barcode">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>XLX Dashboard</h1>
    </div>

            <?php 
                include 'includes/menu.php';
                $barcode = $_POST['barcode'];
                $barcodesearch = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE barcode='$barcode'");
                while($row = $barcodesearch->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $balance = $row['balance'];
                }
            ?>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>Barcode = <?php echo $barcode;?></p>
        <p>Name = <?php echo $name;?></p>
        <p>Balance = $<?php echo $balance;?></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>XLX Glen Iris</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

customerlookup.php (the form for searching a barcode)

```
<div data-role="page" id="customerlookup">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>XLX Dashboard</h1>
    </div>

            <?php include 'includes/menu.php'; ?>

    <div data-role="content">
            <form id="scanbarcode" action="index.php#barcode" method="POST">
                <p>
                    <label for "barcode">Barcode:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcodeinput">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" data-icon="search" id="scanbarcode" value="Search" class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inline">
                </p>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>XLX Glen Iris</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an element with an ID of `barcode` on the `index.php` page? Is this shown conditionally in some way depending on the form submission? In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** and details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've put the code up with everything that I think is relevant. I've tried calling it by a different id during the testing and it still had the same problem.

Comment: And no, the ID of barcode is not conditional. It should be loaded at all times but the only way to browse to it is through the form.